# What means "Unrecognized storage class 111 for .text symbol `._XXXXXXXXX"?

Tags: c++, linker, symbols, aix, libstdc++

I get this error message many times when trying to do objdump of my executable or shared library compiled on AIX 5.3. For any other executable on this machine it works fine.
This executable also crashes at runtime (at string assignment).

I'm not sure if it matters, but during the linking I have few warnings like:
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: non-virtual thunk to XYZ::~XYZ()
Whole executable is build directly from .o files (and one external library, but I'm sure it's fine).

Something tells me that it can be connected to weak symbols, but I have no idea how to solve that problem.
Any idea what could be wrong or what more I can check to proceed with this?

I also tried to include all cpp files in one big file and then compile this. I still get segmentation fault but in other place (now in g_strXXXXX.erase() - erasing of global string).
Part of stack trace looks like this:

(...)

.#3  0x101d8534 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) at ../../licserver/someclass1.cpp:4

.#4  0x101d8df0 in *GLOBAL*_I_fc_softc () at ../../shared/someclass1.cpp:225

.#5  0x103c81fc in *GLOBAL*_FI_licserver_unittest ()

.#6  0xd03aadb0 in mod_init1 () from /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)

.#7  0xd03aacc4 in __modinit () from /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)

.#8  0x100001d4 in __start ()
(gdb) *GLOBAL*_I_fc_softc

So looks like some problem with libc or libstdc++?

Comment: Almost certainly some problem with your code. But if you're not going to post your code, it's very hard to help. Given the stack trace it's possibly something to do with the order in which global variables are initialised, but really hard to tell. Post the code!

Comment: Unlucky I cannot post the code because of two reasons: it's closed source and it have like ~300MB ;) But what I can tell is that it works properly on all windowses, linuxes, HP_UX, MacOS and FreeBSD so I don't think it's code problem. Rather AIX linker or something...

Comment: Do you have global variables defined in different source files? Those will be initalised in different orders with different linkers. That's a common source of bugs when moving from one platform to another.

Comment: Yes, there are few global variables and few singletons around the code. Actually this code was working on AIX before, but stopped after some changes in the build system (previously all files were included in one cpp file, now everything done with proper wildcards, so both order and amount of included files could change). Can you provide me some example of code which could fail because of wrong initialization order? I could imagine that only if one variable would require second one to initialize (and second one would be not initialized yet). Is there any way to debug that kind of problems?

Comment: The comp.lang.c++ FAQ has a good section on this, see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html starting from question 10.14. You're probably going to have to get your hands dirty and mess with the code to pin this down, but if you move things around and suddenly the code starts or stops working for no apparent reason then this issue is likely to be the problem. Not sure about your platform but a debugger should help, just because all this stuff happens before main executes shouldn't mean you can't set breakpoints etc in the normal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were actually right john, thanks a lot!
There was a "static initialization order fiasco" problem with my code.
After replacing all suspicious global objects with function calls problem seems to be solved.

So I changed:

```
CFoo g_F;
```

into:

```
CFoo& GetF() {
  static CFoo F;
  return F;
}
```

And it's fine now. For this part of code I didn't need multithreading support, otherwise I would use singleton I guess (too much code to just rid of that global variables).